# How can I interpret the ratio $\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

let $f'(x)$ the first derivative of function $f(x)$. For some $x_0$, how can I interpret the ratio $\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$ ? More specifically, what does it mean a $\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)} \gg 1$  ?

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly? What is it you are interested in. For instance one can find the result that in a neighborhood of $x_0$ the function $f$ behaves as if it were a constant function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the projected segment length between point of  tangency and x-axis. This length reduces to zero during Newton iteration to find root near a given point. >> 1 means the slope here is low.

EDIT1:

http://www.chem.sc.edu/faculty/morgan/resources/acidbase/nrdoc.html

Comment: By "projected segment length", you mean $x_0-x_1$ (give or take a sign which I don't feel like working out), where $x_1$ is the $x$-coordinate at which the tangent line crosses the $x$-axis.

Comment: Yes, an example is given above.

Comment: In your link the quotient of $f(x_n)$ and $f'(x_n)$ beneath the picture is written in the wrong order.

Comment: Eq 38 is alright.Caption error may be at time of picture making.

Comment: Yes, the formula in the text are okay.